# Custom UnmarshalBSON failing to load data correctly in mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I am experiencing a weird behavior with `UnmarshalBSON` using the official golang mongodb driver.

I got the following code:

```
type MyData struct {
  X int `bson:"x"`
  Y string `bson:"y"`
}

func (d *MyData) UnmarshalBSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias MyData
    aux := &struct {
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(d),
    }
    if err := bson.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I use that code the data returned is as if everything was empty. If I comment the whole function out then `MyData` is filled in correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct implementation:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

type MyData struct {
    X int    `bson:"x"`
    Y string `bson:"y"`
}

func (d *MyData) UnmarshalBSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias MyData
    aux := (*Alias)(d)
    if err := bson.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    buf, err := bson.Marshal(MyData{X: 1, Y: "abc"})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var d MyData
    if err := bson.Unmarshal(buf, &d); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", d)
}
```

Output:

```
main.MyData{X:1, Y:"abc"}
```

---

For the variable `aux` in the question:

```golang
aux := &struct {
    *Alias
}{
    Alias: (*Alias)(d),
}
```

It does not work because `bson.Unmarshal` won't "promote" fields. See it's [implementation to describe a struct](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/97443a6cf7f07c2b6c22d4805ccafd2e77661499/bson/bsoncodec/struct_codec.go#L496-L511). From the perspective of `bson.Unmarshal`, `aux` has only one filed named `Alias`, it does not have the fields `X` or `Y`.

See this example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyData struct {
    X int
    Y string
}

func main() {
    type Alias MyData
    aux := &struct {
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(&MyData{}),
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(*aux)
    t := v.Type()

    // bson.Unmarshal is implemented to list the fields like this:
    fmt.Println("List the fields of the type:")
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        f := t.Field(i)
        fmt.Printf("\tfield %d: %s\n", i+1, f.Name)
    }

    // We can use "FieldByName" to see the promoted fields.
    // But it's not feasible to implemented an unmarshaler with "FieldByName".
    fmt.Printf("\nFind fields with FieldByName:\n")
    for _, fieldName := range []string{"Alias", "X", "Y"} {
        if f, ok := t.FieldByName(fieldName); ok {
            fmt.Printf("\tFound: %s\n", f.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
List the fields of the type:
        field 1: Alias

Find fields with FieldByName:
        Found: Alias
        Found: X
        Found: Y
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got confused because I tried to follow the an example I found for JSON which did the same thing I did from this page: http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/

Comment: That's interesting! The `encoding/json` package 
searches fields in the top struct and then any reachable anonymous structs. See [the typeFields func](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/91b8cc0dfaae12af1a89e2b7ad3da10728883ee1/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L1066-L1069).